# Using youtube-dl with cookies.txt file errors

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I'm trying to download one particular episode. I've logged in to foodnetwork, saved my cookies.txt file, but get these errors when I run `youtube-dl "https://watch.foodnetwork.com/tv-shows/chopped/full-episodes/flavor-savor" --cookies /home/username/Downloads/cookies.txt` Any suggestions? youtube-dl is up-to-date. I also tried reinstalling youtube-dl.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/__main__.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/__init__.py", line 474, in main
  File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/__init__.py", line 464, in _real_main
  File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 2018, in download
  File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 796, in extract_info
  File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py", line 530, in extract
  File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/extractor/discovery.py", line 69, in _real_extract
  File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py", line 2817, in _get_cookies
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/Cookie.py", line 583, in __init__
    if input: self.load(input)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/Cookie.py", line 643, in load
    for k, v in rawdata.items():
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: When you say 'up to date' does the command `youtube-dl --version` report the following: `2019.10.22` ?

Comment: @andrew.46 Yes, correct

Comment: This sounds like a bug in youtube-dl and should be reported to them as a bug for them to fix/address.